# How to open a scanned link in a new webview window AndroidStudio Zxing

Tags: java, android, sdk

I have a barcode scanner application,
    I can't do that
    so that after I scanned QRcode (there’s a link in it),
    so that he opens it in a new webview activity,
    either in pop-up activity

I ask for help, I'm a beginner
       in android studio java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

public class ReaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button scan_btn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reader);
    scan_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan_btn);
    final Activity activity = this;
    scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);

 integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.DATA_MATRIX_TYPES);
            integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
            integrator.setCameraId(0);
            integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
            integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
            integrator.initiateScan();
        }
    });
}

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent     
 data) {
    IntentResult result = 
 IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null){
        if(result.getContents()==null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "You cancelled the scanning", 
  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, 
 result.getContents(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


          }
        }
        else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to load link then please create webView activity then pass your scanner result webView Activity using `putExtras` `getExras`
then load webview in the same activity.